# how to retrieve relevant information belonging to a customer with text files

Tags: java

[image]since im not allowed to use any form of a DB, i cannot logically wire up tables with SQL statements & am left with the option of text files. I have currently 3 text files. The flow goes like this - a Customer makes a Booking which may consists of many Tickets. How do I retrieve & display relevant information @ the console? Any code snippets is greatly appreciated.

3 tables : - Customer, Booking, Ticket

I do know how to read & update data into the text files however.

Comment: Give an example of what your texts files look like and what you would like to extract from them.

Comment: Use .csv files, instead and read/write by using http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ library.

Comment: @peeskillet: Yes Sir, please hang on, i'll update it in a while.

Comment: write the ticket objects to the files and read them as object, better write object state in JSON or XML formats

Answer (score 0):

I would load data from files to some structures and write some class that could operate on them. After work is finished just write back your data to files. If you know how to read and update data in text files you are ready to do this :).

My first though was to create maps of , ,  (where integers are primary keys of "tables"). Doing it that way limit your to searching in "tables" only by their primary keys. Alternatively you can loop over every element in the relevant map and check e.g. CustomerEmail is equal to (...).

I am not quite familiar with Java but you could also check if you can use some kind of DataTable object (or its equivalent in Java) and populate this object with data acquired from file.

Different approach is to use JSON (or XML). Just add some JSON processor to your project ([Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)) and format your data in JSON. Loading data into your application using Jackson (or other JSON library) will be trivial.